# Installing MYSQL using Homebrew on Mac OS 10.11

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I am *installing ruby on rails*.

I followed all the steps given https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite here for **OS X 10.11**.

The problem is while installing MYSQL it shows error that mysql is already installed but not linked. I tried command **sudo brew link mysql** but it is giving me an error. i have attached screenshot of the error.

So can anybody help me to fix this?

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: what are the permissions set for `/usr/local/include`?

Comment: there is no directory named include inside local directory :( but  /usr/local/cellar has only read and execute permissions. i used mkdir to make include directory and it also has only read and executable permissions

Comment: try to `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/include` and try brew again. Alternatively MySQL's website provides a fine `.dmg` file for Mac. Has a nice tool they can install to control MySQL via System Preferences.

Comment: i already did, gave write permission to /include but now its showing **/usr/local/lib is not writable.** error and its not allowing me to give permissions to /lib.

Answer (score 0):

Take ownership of it and everything in it.

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/include
```

Then do another

```
$ brew install mysql
```